# tf namespace resolution

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my tf tree, I accidentally forgot the root forward slash in a single link inside the tree. For example, in the tree in the view_frames output [here](http://zweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/piyushk/share/frames.pdf), the following link:

```
/map -> /ens1/map
```

was accidentally being transmitted by a python node as:

```
map -> ens1/map
```

Now, view_frames clearly ignored this error and formed up everything as a single tree (a full tree was formed - as shown in image above). Similarly tf_echo successfully produced the following transformation:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /segbot1/base_footprint /segbot1/ens1/map
```

Output:

```
At time 459.605
- Translation: [-5.000, -5.000, 0.001]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, 0.000, -0.000]
At time 460.600
- Translation: [-5.000, -5.000, 0.001]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, -0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, 0.000, -0.000]
```

However the navigation stack kept complaining (correctly?) about there being 2 separate trees:

```
Waiting on transform from /segbot1/base_footprint to /segbot1/ens1/map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between '/segbot1/ens1/map' and '/segbot1/base_footprint' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
```

After (quite) a bit of debugging, I found that the tf information was being interpreted as 2 different trees by the move_base node (i.e. Costmap2DRos) in the navigation stack, but as a single tree by view_frames and tf_echo. Although the error has been fixed:

1. Did this happen because because
   the move_base node was launched in
   the /segbot1 namespace and/or
   /segbot1/tf_prefix was set. The
   TransformListener applied standard
   name resolution rules and resolved
   the tf link as /segbot1/map ->
   /segbot1/ens1/map
2. If 1 did indeed
   happen, does it make sense for the
   TransformListener to do this sort of name resolution, as essentially nodes in different namespace see different trees.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43145/tf-namespace-resolution/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I understood, `tf` does not take into account any namespaces. Instead, every node that uses `tf` will accept a `tf_prefix` rosparam which will act similar to namespace in `tf` tree (this is done somehow by magic!). However, if you explicitly put a slash in front of a frame_id in any `tf` function, the `tf_prefix` will be ignored.

When using `view_frame` or `tf_echo` both `/ens1/map` and `ens1/map` are the same (no tf_prefix), however if a `tf_prefix` is set, the second one will become `prefix/ens1/map` while the first one will be the same.

I am not completely sure, but I think robot-specific frames should never be referenced in your code with a forward slash prefix.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-09-06**:
This make a lot of sense. I had an incorrect understanding of tf_prefix. This faq questions is also helpful to this discussion: http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/FAQ#What_is_the_purpose_of_tf_prefix.3F